# Rotate pdf in r

Tags: r, image, pdf, automation, rotation

i am finding a problem to treat some pdf image in r which are rotated.
the code i am using is:

*a = pdftools::pdf_ocr_text("RESULAT-A-O-39-2018-BAT.pdf") %>%
as.data.frame()*

the result i got :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixC9o.png)

the pdf i want to extract data from:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj0bd.png)

i got a lot of files like this, so i must automate all the treatments of the data inside.
thx a lot

Comment: You may have a look into `rotate_pages()` from the staplr-package. You can rotate all the pdfs in your directory and save them to a new directory. Then use `pdf_ocr_text()` on the rotated files.

Comment: thx for the answer. i have tried to install the staplr package but i got the probleme : "Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘staplr’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES' "